# ArrayList adding an employee method and a getter method for it

Tags: java, arraylist

Im trying to do a setter and getter for an arraylist. 
what am i doing wrong

```
  // Method to add employee

   public void addEmployee(Employee newGuy)
   {
      this.employee = newGuy;   
   }

// Method to get new employee

   public Employee getEmployees()
   {
      return employee;
   }
```

Comment: Im getting an incompatble types error. Employee cannot be converted to ArrayList<Employee>

Comment: How do i fix this, do i need to cast or sumthing

Comment: You should edit your question and not comment it. How is the member definded? `public Employee employee;` What's about the surrounding class? You should post more informations.

Comment: `employee.add(newGuy);`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

If you want to add an `Employee` to an `ArrayList` of `Employee`s, all you have to do is to use the `add` method:

```
employees.add(newGuy);
```

[ArrayList.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E))

```
public void setEmployees(ArrayList<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}
```

And to get the `ArrayList`:

```
public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}
```

Comment: ok thank you. And then to return it in the getter do i just do: return employees ?

Comment: Yes, that's all u have to do.

Comment: public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}   // getting an error with this: incompatible types: List<Employee> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Employee>, // i followed the code above but still getting this error

Comment: @DanielMcHenry change `setEmployees(List<Employee> employees)` to `setEmployees(ArrayList<Employee> employees)`

Comment: That fixed it. ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning a new employee then you have to create a new one like this:

```
public Employee getEmployees(){
      return new Employee();
}
```

Comment: Okay so now i have two more methods i need to include. A sortByName() method that tells me in the instructions i need to use a Comparator interface object and a sort by salary and it hints at using Collections.sort() , So do i need to change my class signature to implement the Comparator interface. like: public class CompanyDataBase implements Comparator<CompanyDataBase>

Comment: Yes you have to say that the class you are in implements Comparator. You are correct.

Comment: // method to compare by name
   public List<Employee> sortByName(ArrayList<Employee> employees)
   {
      public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) 
      {
         if(e1.getName() < e2.getName())
         {
            return 1;
         } 
         else 
         {
            return -1;
         } // is this on the right track or am i away off??

Comment: That looks correct. Does it run correctly? If not, please paste the code in the code brackets, so it's easier to read.

Comment: CompanyDataBase.java:34: error: illegal start of expression
      public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) And also this error: CompanyDataBase.java:34: error: not a statement
      public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) 
                                       ^

Comment: public List<Employee> sortByName(ArrayList<Employee> employees)
   {
      public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) 
      {
         if(e1.getName() < e2.getName())
         {
            return 1;
         } 
         else 
         {
            return -1;
         }
   }

Comment: omit the 'public' when defining the int.

Comment: CompanyDataBase.java:34: error: not a statement
      int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2)
// sorry whats wrong here

Comment: Honestly I think you might have some syntax errors that are easily found by you. Here is a website and an example that I used when i was learning how to use this interface. http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/

Answer (score 0):

like this you can create setters and getters for your ArrayList<>().

```
 ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}

public void setEmployees(ArrayList<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 this.employee=newGuy;
```

use

```
 employee.add(newGuy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setters and Getters for a `List<E>` does not work in the way you think they do.

Setters and Getters can work like this.

```
public void setEmployee(ArrayList<Employee> employees)
{
    this.employees = employees;   
}

public List<Employee> getEmployees()
{
    return employees;
}
```

However that overrides resp. get the list of employees. However want you probabbly want to achieve is to add an employee resp. get a certain employee. This can be accomplished in many different ways.

```
public void addEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    empployees.add(employee);
}

public Employee getEmployees(int index)
{
    return employees.get(index);
}
```

The getter requires an index for which employee you want to find. This can also be accomplished with different keys. See [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for example.

Working with a `List<E>` is different than working directly with an entry, in this case an `Employee`. The `List<E>` can hold anywhere from none to many Employees. I suggest having a readw up on the [List Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) from the Java API. I also suggest looking at examples of different ways to work with the `List<E>` and `Map<K,V>` interfaces.